# template match - how to specify OR conditon

Tags: xslt

I want to specify a match expression in a template that will get invoked on multiole namespaces of element:

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='abc.com' or namespace-uri()='def.com']">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

But this does not seem to work.  It only gets invoked if left side of or expression is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to work with namespaces is to declare them e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:abc="http://example.com/abc"
  xmlns:def="http://example.com/def"
  exclude-result-prefixes="abc def">

<xsl:template match="abc:* | def:*">...</xsl:template>

...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That being said, I don't see anything wrong with your `or` predicate expression, other than that you haven't provided any input you use it with.

Comment: I cant use 'abc:*' nor 'def:*' because they could be different from file to file, but they always use the samenamespace uri.  One file might be xmlns:abc="xxx" and another file might be xmlns:bcd="xxx" so I can only use namespace-uri() = 'xxx'.
My test case worked, so I must have something else wrong. Thanks.

Comment: bretter, are you aware that the prefix choosen in the XSLT stylesheet does not need to match the one in the XML input? So you can use the approach I posted, just choose a prefix you want, declare it with the namespace URI of the XML input, then write your stylesheet. That way the match or selection will work, even if the XML input uses different prefixes, as long as the URIs match.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='abc.com' or namespace-uri()='def.com']"> 
      ... 
    </xsl:template>

But this does not seem to work.
```

**This *is correct code*.**

So, the problem is in the code that you haven't shown to us. Please, also provide a simple XML document so that everyone could apply the provided XSLT code to the provided XML document and repro the problem.

**Here is a demonstration that the "suspected" code is correct**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='def.com' or namespace-uri()='abc.com']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<a>
 <b:b xmlns:b="abc.com">
  <c/>
 </b:b>
 <f/>
 <d:d xmlns:d="def.com">
  <e/>
 </d:d>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<b:b xmlns:b="abc.com">
   <c/>
</b:b>
<d:d xmlns:d="def.com">
   <e/>
</d:d>
```